# PHP: How to add the missing tags in each group of elements in XML?

Tags: php, xml

This is the XML that we have right now:

```
<persons>
    <person>
        <firstname>John</firstname>
        <surname>Doe</surname>
        <age></age>
    </person>
    <person>
        <firstname>Jane</firstname>
        <surname>Doe</surname>
        <age></age>
        <sex>Female</sex>
    </person>
</persons>
```

As you could see the first group of elements only has three tags namely firstname, surname, and age while the second group has an additional tag name sex.

What we need is to make all the element groups in the XML contains all the tags that each group has, in this case the first group should also contain the sex tag but in a blank state as well like this:

```
<persons>
    <person>
        <firstname>John</firstname>
        <surname>Doe</surname>
        <age></age>
        <sex></sex>
    </person>
    <person>
        <firstname>Jane</firstname>
        <surname>Doe</surname>
        <age></age>
        <sex>Female</sex>
    </person>
</persons>
```

Also what if there's a third, fourth or on the 50th group has another new tag named nickname? In this case all the group should have the tag nickname as well but in a blank state.

How could I do this efficiently in PHP?

Comment: Do you have to have them in the XML or do you have to have them in the Domain Model? Will anything else but your application read and write to the XML?

Comment: On an XML, no Domain Model used here. A different application is writing this kind of XML and we would like to update the XML file before using it in our system then storing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [SimpleXML](http://php.net/SimpleXML), the script makes two passes: one to find all the possible tags, the other to create empty elements:

```
$str = <<<STR

<persons>
    <person>
        <firstname>John</firstname>
        <surname>Doe</surname>
        <age></age>
    </person>
    <person>
        <firstname>Jane</firstname>
        <surname>Doe</surname>
        <age></age>
        <sex>Female</sex>
    </person>
</persons>

STR;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);

// Create an array of all the possible tags
$tags = array();
foreach($xml->person as $person)
{
    $current_tags = array_keys(get_object_vars($person));
    $tags = array_unique(array_merge($tags, $current_tags));
}

// Add empty tags to elements who don't have them
foreach($xml->person as $person)
{
    foreach($tags as $tag)
    {
        if(!property_exists($person, $tag))
        {
            $person->$tag = '';
        }
    }
}

// Output the new XML
echo $xml->asXML();
```

Comment: This works well, adding the tags dynamically. I may be mistaken, but it seems the XSLT versions in the other answers require you to manually add new tags to the XSL. This does it automatically which is what the question called for.

Comment: @Herbert: True, the XSLT solutions require adjustment if the schema changes. If the solution must be dynamic, then Tim's solution would work. If not, then the XSLT solutions would work.

Comment: @Dan: Point taken, but why do manually what you can automate? ;)

Comment: @Herbert With a dynamic approach you will only get nodes that exist at least once in the source XML. If an expected node is missing in all elements, it will simply not appear, which might lead to undesired effects. The XSLT (!= Schema btw) allows you keep the destination format exactly like you need it. It works like an adapter and makes sure external changes cannot ripple to your application. It also doubles as documentation for the format expected in your application and should be significantly faster.

Comment: @Gordon: I agree, but what if you don't know what fields to expect in the first place? (i.e. no schema/DTD). "_what if there's a third, fourth or on the **50th** group has another new tag_" lead me to the conclusion that officeboi was looking for something that could analyze the XML file. It might not be a bad idea to use the analysis to _create_ a transform though.

Comment: @Herbert if you dont know what to expect, you dont use the service :) I mean whats the point in consuming arbitrary random data? Your app has to know at least some structures in it, to do something meaningful with it. Unfortunately, officeboi doesnt say what hes doing with the data. Infering the Schema from the XML is definitely possible but it takes much more effort (and you'd still need an additional processing to pad the missing elements after that). See http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/0104_generating_xml_schemas_from_xml.html - but if the above works for the OP: good :)

Comment: @Gordon: Again, I wholeheartedly agree. Personally, I wouldn't dream of using a service that produces arbitrary data. But... What the OP wants... well... that's what the OP gets. :) Of course, he doesn't say it even comes from a service. Maybe it was hand-coded or maybe monkeys puked it up or maybe... I suppose it's a moot point now. I just supported the solution because it answers the OP's question. :) I see your point about inferring the schema. If it comes from a service there should be a Schema in place or at least a DTD for cryin' out loud.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest to make this maintainable over a long time (e.g. anticipating more new fields and stuff like that) would be to process the XML with an XSLT that contains all the required fields:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/persons">
    <persons>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="person"/>
    </persons>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="person">
    <person>
        <firstname><xsl:value-of select="firstname"/></firstname>
        <surname><xsl:value-of select="surname"/></surname>
        <age><xsl:value-of select="age"/></age>
        <sex><xsl:value-of select="sex"/></sex>
    </person>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then, whenever you get a new copy from the generator service, do ([manual](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.transformtoxml.php))

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('people.xml');
$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('people.xsl');
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);
echo $proc->transformToXML($dom);
```

This will produce ([demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/RxGpLq))

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<persons>
  <person>
    <firstname>John</firstname>
    <surname>Doe</surname>
    <age/>
    <sex/>
  </person>
  <person>
    <firstname>Jane</firstname>
    <surname>Doe</surname>
    <age/>
    <sex>Female</sex>
  </person>
</persons>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but we need it to be automated since we won't know if there is a new tag added on the XML file given to us. But I learned something new here thanks to you!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Gordon that the best solution here is XSLT. However, I suggest using a slightly different XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="person">
        <person>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *[not(self::sex)]"/>
            <sex><xsl:value-of select="sex"/></sex>
        </person>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I [tried it out](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog_ex1) with W3Schools' online XSLT evaluator and it works as requested.

Comment: How does this differ from Gordon's solution? Can it add fields dynamically without adding them manually to the XSL file. That seems to be what officeboi is asking for. My vote goes to @Tim's solution.